# Guava cachebuilder - put when load in progress

Tags: java, caching, guava

Consider this simple program:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache;

public class Main {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        final LoadingCache<Integer, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
                new CacheLoader<Integer, String>() {

                    @Override
                    public String load(Integer arg0) throws Exception {
                        logger.info("Cache builder START: " + arg0);
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        logger.info("Cache builder FINISH: " + arg0);
                        return "This is what CacheBuilder returned for key " + arg0;
                    }
                });

        Thread getterThread = new Getter(cache);
        getterThread.start();

        Thread setterThread = new Setter(cache);
        setterThread.start();

        getterThread.join();
        setterThread.join();

        logger.info("Finally in cache we have: " + cache.get(1));

    }

    private static final class Getter extends Thread {
        private final LoadingCache<Integer, String> cache;

        private Getter(LoadingCache<Integer, String> cache) {
            this.cache = cache;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                logger.info("Getter thread reads 1st time " + cache.get(1)
                        + "  <<<<<<<<<< WHAT !?!");
                // allow the setter to put the value
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                logger.info("Getter thread reads 2nd time " + cache.get(1));
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class Setter extends Thread {
        private final LoadingCache<Integer, String> cache;

        private Setter(LoadingCache<Integer, String> cache) {
            this.cache = cache;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // deliberately wait to allow the Getter thread
                // trigger cache loading
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cache.put(1, "This isn't where I parked my car!");
                logger.info("Setter thread now reads: " + cache.get(1));
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
2013-11-08 15:24:32 INFO Main$1 load Cache builder START: 1
2013-11-08 15:24:32 INFO Main$Setter run Setter thread now reads: This isn't where I parked my car!
2013-11-08 15:24:36 INFO Main$1 load Cache builder FINISH: 1
2013-11-08 15:24:36 INFO Main$Getter run Getter thread reads 1st time This is what CacheBuilder returned for key 1  <<<<<<<<<< WHAT !?!
2013-11-08 15:24:37 INFO Main$Getter run Getter thread reads 2nd time This isn't where I parked my car!
2013-11-08 15:24:37 INFO Main main Finally in cache we have: This isn't where I parked my car!
```

I'm getting this "This is what CacheBuilder returned for key 1" in Getter thread. 
Obviously this is because the get(1) called by Getter triggers cache loading, but meanwhile the Setter thread comes and puts some other value for key 1.
I'd expect it to return the same what was just put before by Setter = "This isn't where I parked my car!" (which I get the 2nd time Getter retrieves value for 1).

Did I miss something ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The internal data structures of the cache are synchronized to protect you against pollution like that. The model in your head should be: As long as a thread is using the cache, it has its own copy.

So the first thread triggers the cache loading. Guava "clones" the cache (internally, it just makes sure no one can change the structures thread 1 is seeing). After 4 seconds, the thread gets the result returned by the cache loading, no matter how many other threads change the value in the mean time (they all get their own "copy" to modify).

When thread 1 is finished, the cache updates itself. Now the change from thread 2 becomes visible for thread 1.

Comment: But the thread 1 (Getter) calls the get(1) twice. The first time it gets the value from cache loader, fine. But the next time it calls get(1) it already sees the value set by the other thread (Setter).

Comment: As I said: You get the current value. As t1 was calculating the initial value, it got that - t2 can't interrupt/mess with t1's data. When the first get() has finished, the internal state is synced for all threads. From then on, t1 will see the changes of t2. It's *not* necessary for t1 or t2 to terminate to trigger the sync. The sync happens as soon as get() returns.